# Karate how to send server SSL certificate client.crt

Tags: karate

I want to convert the following curl command into a Karate script:

```
curl --cacert ca.crt --key client.key --cert client.crt "https://myurl"
```

All three SSL parts are required, i.e. client cert, client key AND server cert.

Is this possible in Karate?

Comment: I can only point you to the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#x509-certificate-authentication - you can also search stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+certificate

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this I converted ca.crt, client.key and client.crt into a .pfx file using this command:

openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey client.key -in client.crt -certfile CA.crt

This created a file called certificate.pfx

I then added this line to karateconfig.js:

```
  karate-configure('ssl', { trustAll: true });
```

I copied my new certificate.pfx file into this location:

src\test\resources\sslCertificates\certificate.pfx

I added the following line to the Background section of my feature file:

```
* configure ssl = { keyStore: 'classpath:sslCertificates/certificate.pfx', keyStorePassword: '', keyStoreType: 'pkcs12' }
```

I then received a successful response for my request.